# make: execvp Permission denied , Error 127

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin

I am trying to run an executable from makefile using cygwin make, The executable has proper permissions, still make fails saying permission denied, Error log :

```
C:\jenkins\workspace\donotship\sdk>make exe  

ls -l  C:/jenkins/workspace/donotship/sdk/InstallAnywhere/build.exe  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 c_celuru Domain Users 558368 Oct 20 16:27 C:/jenkins/workspace/donotship/sdk/InstallAnywhere/build.exe
C:/jenkins/workspace/donotship/sdk/InstallAnywhere/build.exe
make: execvp: C:/jenkins/workspace/donotship/sdk/InstallAnywhere/build.exe: Permission denied
Makefile:463: recipe for target 'exe' failed
make: *** [exe] Error 127
```

The makefile contains following instructions for exe target

```
exe:
    ls -l  C:/jenkins/workspace/donotship/sdk/InstallAnywhere/build.exe  
    C:/jenkins/workspace/sdk/InstallAnywhere/build.exe
```

I am able to execute `C:/jenkins/workspace/sdk/InstallAnywhere/build.exe` from command line but not through make.

When I run `C:/jenkins/workspace/sdk/InstallAnywhere/build.exe` manually I get a popup saying "Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to this computer", to avoid this I changed "User Account control settings" in control panel to "Never Notify".From then I can execute build.exe without previous popup, but from make,  it fails saying permission denied

Comment: Is all that really on a single line? (It appears to be an `ls -l` command plus its output; those will never be on the same line). Can you post the rule that is being executed?

Comment: @reinierpost: No, it was a bad edit. I reverted to my earlier version, which makes the output a little clearer (OP had no formatting at all).

Comment: OK, thanks. Still, I see no execution of `make` here, and no recipe for the `exe` target. Without data it's kind of hard to reach a conclusion.

Comment: After Running command prompt as administrator, running make solves the issue. I think running the executable from make requires administrator privileges.I am wondering how it worked when I run it from command line manually(launched command prompt without any administration privileges). I tried the same with shell script, even shell script also requires administration privileges